# Editing htaccess file to redirect only content + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I have created a subfolder in my webserver and installed wordpress there, it's working ok. And now i have created several subdomains. I need to show pages made in the wordpress installation in those subdomains but without changing the addess shown in the web browser address bar.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/WPweb/index.php/pagetobeshown [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

with this i am being redirected and content is shown ok, but the address bar is changed.

is it possible to fix this so that address is not changed?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want all URL-paths under the subdomain to display the same page? (Although that wouldn't necessary be good for SEO.) Or just the document root of the subdomain?

Comment: I have an old page in the main directory, i have created a subdir for a wordpress install (/web/WPweb) where i created several pages with wordpress.
Now i have 5 subdomains which i want to show the pages a created in the wordpress install, but i need the address bar to show that subdomain

so when someone enter sub1.domain.com, it shows https://example.com/WPweb/index.php/page1 content but the address bar shows sub1.example.com
when someone enter sub2.example.com, it shows https://example.com/WPweb/index.php/page2 content but the address bar shows sub2.example.com
... etc

Answer (score 0):

To do this in `.htaccess` you would need to configure your server as a *reverse proxy* and proxy the request from the subdomain to the URL on the main domain. WordPress will then see this as a request for the main domain.

However, this does require some configuration in your server config to ensure the appropriate modules are loaded (mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, etc.) and optionally to set `ProxyPassReverse` if WordPress should issue any redirects.

You can then use the `P` flag with mod_rewrite's `RewriteRule` to send the request through mod_proxy. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/WPweb/index.php/pagetobeshown [P]
```

This sends requests for `https://sub.example.com/` *only* (ie. the document root of the subdomain) to the URL as stated. The `NC`, `QSA` and `L` flags are not required.

If you want to send *any* URL-path (as implied by your `RewriteRule` directive) to the URL on the target site then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^$` to `^` (simply remove the `$`). However, this many-to-one relationship is not necessarily good for SEO.

You will still need to modify the `rel="canonical"` link elements in the page to the appropriate URL in WordPress itself.

However, I'm sure there is a better, more WordPress-specific way to solve this. But WordPress would need to be configured to accept requests to the subdomain and the alternative URL-path.

Comment: So my web hosting is telling me they can't activate those modules because it is a shared server. Do i have any other option to achieve this?, the main goal is to show the content of a page (in the wordpress subfolder installation) when acces to a subdomain, whithout chaning the address bar.

Comment: You'll need to configure WordPress to accept requests to these additional subdomains (since WP is, by default, "fixed" to your main domain). You'll also need to make these additional URL-paths (for the subdomains) route to the same WP page. The subdomains will need to point to the same place on the filesystem as the main domain - if they are not already (or you'll need to rewrite the request further using mod_rewrite). You may get a better response on the WordPress Stack for this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/